# Omit name attribute of input tag in URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, input

I want the server to behave such as when I submit a name the URL will be updated following the format **localhost:3000/*userinput***. Its current result is **localhost:3000/*?name=userinput***. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

**ExpressJs FILE**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>

        function garbageCollector() {
            let form = document.getElementById("name-form")
            form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault()
                let name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value 
                window.location.href = "localhost:3000/" + name
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="name-form" onsubmit="">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="Enter your name" id="name" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="name-submit-btn">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**NodeJs FILE**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node listening on port 3000')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('name_input')
})

app.get('/:name', function (req, res) {
    let name = req.params.name
    let age = req.query.age
    if (age === undefined) {
        res.render('age_input')
    }
    else {
        res.send(`Hello ${name}. You are ${age}`)
    }
})

/*app.get('/age', function (req, res) {
    res.render('age_input')
})*/
```

Comment: It should work as expected by default submission.

Comment: So there's no way to modify or customize it as I want?

Comment: I can't understand what the issue is. The code you provided should do exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a post method, not a get

```
app.post('/name', function (req, res) {
    let {name,age}=req.body
    if (age === undefined) {
        res.render('age_input')
    }
    else {
        res.send(`Hello ${name}. You are ${age}`)
    }
})
```

Comment: As I know POST doesn't put anything onto the URL bar, and it's usage is to update some data, not requesting. Can you explain a bit more about using POST?